# "No usable browser found" error when using Emacs to browse HyperSpec

Tags: browser, emacs, common-lisp

I would like to use Emacs to access [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/) (html pages for Common Lisp ANSI standard).

Here's what I've done:

1. downloaded, untared, and copied HyperSpec files it into `~/.emacs.d/HyperSpec/`;
2. downloaded "clhs.el" and put it into `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/`;
3. added line `(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-rooot "~/.emacs.d/HyperSpec/")` into my `.emacs` file;
4. tried <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `slime-hyperspec-lookup` <kbd>RET</kbd> `do*` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

After entering of this command I get the following error:

> No usable browser found

Although I love Emacs and I used it for about two years, I didn't browse anything with it, so I don't know what kind of browser the error message says about.

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an default browser environment variable set you can use (eval or put in .emacs)

```
(setq browse-url-generic-program 
    (executable-find (getenv "BROWSER")) 
     browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic)
```

if no BROWSER environmental variable is set you can replace

```
(executable-find (getenv "BROWSER"))
```

with `(executable-find "your browser call")` or the absolute path to your browser.

Comment: Could you give me the output of M-x eval-expression (executable-find (getenv "BROWSER")) ? And what system do you use?

Comment: Or you could try (executable-find "what you call chrome with from commandline") in eval-expression if it doesn't return nil use that instead

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this overview of configuring [url browsing](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseUrl), which is what the hyperspec lookup depends on.

You can also observe other people's schemes for configuring this by looking at their init files code, say [at github](https://github.com/search?l=emacs-lisp&q=browse-url-browser-function&ref=opensearch&type=Code).

Once you have it working, then you may also find [w3m](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/w3m) useful, I do.  That renders web pages inside of an emacs buffer.   And later, you might enjoy my [slime-documentation-search](https://gist.github.com/bhyde/5735219).